# Does drawing out blood while fasting break the fast?

Tags: sawm, ramadan

Hello I want to run some tests in hospital (for my health) and I need to take out my blood for this occasion, I'm wondering is there anything I should look out for (like the blood thing) in order **NOT** to break my fast?

Note :

I don't have to do it during the Ramadan, but it's the most convenient time for me.

**Additional explanation:**

I'm not ill in any way (I think). But this is one of those once-per-year check-ups that everyone ought to do sick or not.

If I were sick I'd proceed with any treatment if needed, including blood tests or what not.

Comment: Purely a health advisory: this site is not a medical one; please also consult qualified medical practitioners before making decisions about treatment. This is not aimed solely at @ant, but also at any other readers. My understanding (as a non-Muslim) is that Islam also places great emphasis on human life, and there may be allowances due to medical needs.

Comment: Oh, second note: it is important (especially with blood tests) that the medical team are aware that you are, or have been, fasting - especially if you are not in a predominantly Muslim region (where the team may not realise). Fasting can change levels of various chemicals, and the team may need to read the results differently.

Comment: @MarcGravell just a suggestion, it seems that you are reluctant to answer(correct me if im wrong,) and usually choose to answer in the comments section, i would like to remind you this is not an islamic webisite, rather a website about islam, you are more than welcolme to answer

Comment: @NesreenA the question is clearly asking for an Islamic perspective, which I am not qualified to answer. However, whenever a question relating to health comes up (it happens on Christianity.SE too), I am of the opinion that these things need to be said. It is a dangerous legal area, etc. I will be ***very*** happy to provide an answer, should a question arise where I feel I can add genuine value. For me, that might mean a question relating to interacting with non-believers, or explaining the bizarre views of non-believers. If it comes up, call me :)

Comment: i edited my answer accordingly to add safety hazard problems

Answer (score 10, accepted):

there are 2 reasons why scholars have deemed this as breaking your fast:

- one is from a hadith about vomiting volentary and involentary

> the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever vomits involuntarily does not have to make up the fast, but whoever vomits deliberately let him make up the fast.” Narrated by al-Tirmidhi, 720, classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Tirmidhi, 577.

this would mean that is somthing comes out of the body volentarily, such as a cut, nosebleed, etc, then your fast is valid. But if one deliberatly tries to expell nutriants, then their fast is invalid.

- the second reason is because of a hadith about cupping- a medicinal practice that involves removing blood from the body to ease pain. read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cupping_therapy#Wet_Cupping_.28Al-Hijamah_or_medicinal_bleeding.29)

> the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “The cupper and the one for whom cupping is done have both invalidated their fast.” Narrated by Abu Dawood, 2367; classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh Abi Dawood, 2047.

taking out blood to run tests is the same, since it is deliberatly pulling blood out of the body, even if it is for your health.

I would also like to point out that if you are fasting and you pull blood out it may be a safety hazard, as you are loosing neseccary nutrients. This may be one of the reasons why the prophet seemed it as breaking your fast

unless it is absoulutly necessary to run tests at that moment (which im assuming it isn't) you cannot break you fast. Even though it may be easier to do it in ramadan, it would be best to postpone your appointment. This month of ramadan is about sacrafice, and it is not limited to food.

If this is necessary, Allah said in the quran:

> [Fasting is for] a limited number of days. So whoever among you is ill or on a journey [during them] - then an equal number of days [are to be made up]. And upon those who are able [to fast, but with hardship] - a ransom [as substitute] of feeding a poor person [each day]. And whoever volunteers excess - it is better for him. **But to fast is best for you**, if you only knew. 2:184

If you truley are ill, then it would be permissible to give the blood, and break your fast, and feed a poor person for each day you break. But if it can be postponed, it would be preferred.

Comment: A lot of blood tests for diabetes/blood type/HIV only takes a drop. It doesn't seem to be quite the same analogy as cupping or vomiting. But does explain that blood donations and significant blood tests break your fast.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Voluntary Blood Donor. I saw Fatwa at clinic that giving blood does not break fast from our local ulama few days ago.
I don't know how they made that conclusion but I suppose they should be serious about these things.

Comment: wow; that's hardcore blood donation; when I give blood, they want me to drink a pint of fluid first, and usually a drink + biscuit after (to avoid faintness etc). I applaud your determination.